# Problems with URL handling with Spring Boot and Angular 2

Tags: url, angular, spring-boot, routes

I am trying to develop an application with Spring Boot for the back end and Angular 2 for the front end, using maven.

The angular 2 front end is in the `src/main/resources/static` dir of the project.

When I enter the `http://localhost:8080/` URL in my browser, all is fine: I can access the angular 2 front end, and the front end can communicate with the rest api perfectly. My angular 2 routing works fine: when I click on a link on the front end, I go the right page and the browser url bar shows the right things (ie. `http://localhost:8080/documents`)

But the problem is when I try to directly write the same URL in the browser. Spring take over the front end and says the is no mapping for `/documents`.

Is there a way to tell spring boot to only "listen" to `/api/*` URL and to "redirect" all the others to the front end?

Here is my Spring Controller class:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class MyRestController {

    @Autowired
    private DocumentsRepository documentRepository;

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/documents/list",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = "application/json")
    public Iterable<RfDoc> findAllDocuments() {
        return documentRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

Here is the main application class:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Here is my app.route.ts:

```ts
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig }  from '@angular/router';
import { DocumentComponent } from './doc.component';  

const routes: RouterConfig = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'documents',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: "documents",
        component: DocumentComponent
    }
];

export const appRouterProviders = [
    provideRouter(routes)
];
```

Comment: There is a way to listen /api/* only . For that you need to have a Filter.

Comment: How can I do that? I'm pretty new to this stuff...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I found a perfectly fine solution (for me, at least): I change my location for the old AngularJS 1.X way, with the # in the URL (i.e. `http://localhost:8080/#/documents` ).

To obtain this behaviour, I change my bootstrap like this

```
import { bootstrap }      from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent }         from './app.component';
import { appRouterProviders }   from './app.routes';
import { AuthService }          from './auth.service';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [AuthService,
    appRouterProviders,
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
]);
```

Hope this can help somebody!

Comment: Don't use the uglt hashtag notation ...just keep the HTML5 location strategy and redirect all your angular2's routes to the index.html file. Dont redirect all the routes as you will need them for your end points resources (the rest controllers).

Comment: How can I do the redirection?

Comment: Eric please create a question and post the link so I can past some code.